# Rotativa pdf converter works very slow on server

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

I use rotativa 1.6.4 nuget package to convert html to pdf in .net mvc5 project with vs 2013 ide. It works fine at my local. But, after I published to server('Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard' arvixe shared servers); everything works fine except pdf conversion page. It results very slow (more than 30 seconds).

Then I puplished to another server('64 bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and IIS 7.5'), it works without any problem here.

Any advice ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the root cause was here ?

Comment: I discussed it a lot with help desk of arvixe and I convinced them it is not about memory or cpu issue, but they couldn't solve it. Rotativa doesn't work in arvixe shared hosting properly. Then, I changed my shared hosting company, everything is fine now.

Comment: Which hosting did you switch to ?

Comment: I'm in the same boat. My PDF takes 45 seconds to show. Can't figure out how to fix it. Which shared hosting did you jump onto ?

Comment: A bit late in the game. If there is any css file links in your pdf views, use @Server.MapPath() instead.

Answer (score 2):

Old question and all, I know....but I just had the same problem.
Using Rotativa.PartialViewAsPdf my pdf took around 20 seconds to render.
After a lot of troubleshooting I narrowed it down to an external stylesheet reference.

Changing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

to this (adding only **https:**)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

fixed my problem.

The PDF now renders in 3 seconds flat.

Comment: I had a slowness issue as well and it turned out to be bootstrap in the view that was slowing it down. adding argument "--print-media-type" solved the issue. Now my view was very simple and it printed basically the same, I can see if you are trying to print rich content how that may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Other case is about the compiled version of wkhtmltopdf.exe on package, i replaced the .exe file on the project and replaced by the latest version and this "do the magic"

Answer (score 0):

I have same Problem.
Rotativa was working good but after server changed it worked slow. I found Some CSS and Javascript link added, I removed all the link it working good now.
Also some images is not loading so it is loading slow.

```
Eg.  < img src="/Images/arriw.png" / >
   <  script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script >
```

When i removed all these thing it working very fast.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using UrlAsPdf() along with just adding the cookie that I needed, had resolved the issue. Following is the sample code that I have used.

```
var report = new UrlAsPdf(url);

Dictionary<string, string> cookieCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var key in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
{
   if (Crypto.Hash("_user").Equals(key))
   {
      cookieCollection.Add(key, Request.Cookies.Get(key).Value);
      break;
   }
}
report.Cookies = cookieCollection;
report.FormsAuthenticationCookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
```