# Rotativa PDF export taking significantly longer on Windows Server 2016 after recent update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, server, rotativa

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4.6 web application running on a 64-bit Windows Server 2016. The application utilizes Rotativa 1.7.3 to generate and export PDF documents. Previously, the PDF export process was fast, typically taking less than 3 seconds. However, after a recent Windows update on the server, the export process now takes approximately 45 seconds.

I'm using Rotativa here to convert a Partial View as a PDF and then use it as an attachment in an email or show it in a new tab.
Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
Rotativa.PartialViewAsPdf salesQuotePdf = new Rotativa.PartialViewAsPdf("_PrintableSalesQuote", pricingToolModel);
byte[] salesQuotepdfData = salesQuotePdf.BuildFile(ControllerContext);
```

The slowdown seems to occur specifically within the BuildFile function call. Interestingly, the issue is not occurring when we access the IIS website from server machine using localhost but the issue is occuring when accessing the same IIS website from other machines via domain name.

I've researched similar issues and came across an old thread on Stack Overflow ([Rotativa pdf converter works very slow on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613256/rotativa-pdf-converter-works-very-slow-on-server)), but none of the proposed solutions resolved the problem.

Could anyone suggest potential causes or solutions to this slowdown issue with Rotativa PDF generation on Windows Server 2016? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: We can't guess what your code is doing, what else is running on your server or what `a recent Windows update` means - Windows Server 2016 mainstream support ended 2 years ago. Perhaps a new antivirus was installed? Perhaps the Spectre patch was applied 6 years too late?

Comment: From my event viewer log, below is some of the information I can share:
```
Date: 11/2/2024
Information log: Installation Started: Windows has started installing the following update: 2024-01 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB5034119)
```
There are a few more related logs. Let me know if these logs might be useful for my question.

Comment: I'll have to repeat the comment - we can't know what's going on on your machine. Rotativa doesn't convert anything to PDF itself, it calls a bundled version of wkhtml2pdf.exe. And since Rotativa hasn't been updated since 2018, that's a very *old* version too. The event you posted doesn't help and probably doesn't apply at all. You'll have to check what's running on the production server, whether wkhtml2pdf.exe is running, pegging a core to 100%, whether an antivirus is running at the same time thus blocking the application.

Comment: If the problem is an outdated version of kwhtml2pdf, you may be able to solve it by replacing the 7-year-old copy of wkhtml2pdf.exe with a newer one.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf does work on the server. Unfortunately, converting the pdf in byte[] is still too slow.
`byte[] salesQuotepdfData = salesQuotePdf.BuildFile(ControllerContext);`